# Need help identifying this connector from a Pulsar Taximeter

Tags: connector, identification

This is the primary mounting connector for Pulsar 2010, 2020 & 2030 Taximeters.
I have looked many times and have never seen this exact one...

It is symmetrical with 5 pins.  The pins have lip on the outside edge that after they have been crimped cause them to lock to casing.

Hopefully the pictures are clear enough.

Thanks.

---

Ok, here is a scale as requested.

[image: mm scale]

[image: Back area]

[image: Front]
[image: angle on mounting bracket]

Comment: What's the pitch?

Comment: @TomL.  Added a scale photo as requested.

Comment: @TomL. - That pitch looks like it *might* be almost, but not quite, 8mm - perhaps around 7.6mm which happens to be 0.3 inches? (Thanks for adding the photo, GB - AE7OO)

Comment: @SamGibson I'll add one with inches seeing how that is most likely what it was specified in originally.  The 2030s date from 2003, the 2020 from 1997 and I can't remember when the 2010 was release, but much earlier.  Ekkk... I can't, I just installed my last harness...Arrgghhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like TE part [54489-5](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/54489-5/A121070-ND/479793) pitch is .312"

[image]

Contacts [53892-2](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/53892-2/A104025CT-ND/2816423) are seperate from the housing.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you.  While it does not mount the same, the contact  interaction is compatible..